# thermodynamic related integral question

Tags: integration

[image]

To calculate the area under region 1 or region 2 or region 1 and 2, my book always divides by 2, and then multiplies by the change in volume..

Say I want area under region 1 and 2, the book does (320+200)/2*0.05 to get the area under the region 1 and 2. I am confused because wouldn't adding 320 and 200 overlap 200 in 320 since 320 already includes the area for 200?

Now to find the area in region 2 they do (320-200)/2*0.05..

I am confused where these /2 area coming from and also confused about the overlapping of area in (320+200)/2*0.05

Please explain.

Comment: This follows from the formula for area of a trapezium which is $\frac{1}{2}\cdot $ (sum of parallel sides)$\times $  height.  andraiamatrix derives this in his answer below.

Answer (score 0):

So to find the area of region II, they are simply finding the area of the triangle. The base of the triangle is $b = 1.00-0.05 = 0.05$ and the height of the triangle is $h = (320 - 200$). Then from geometry, the area of a triangle is: $${bh\over 2} =  {(0.05)(320-200) \over 2 }$$

Next, to find region I, you would take the area of the rectangle with length $l = 200$ and width $w = 1.00-0.05 = 0.05$. So the area of region I is length x width = 200 x 0.05

Then the total area of regions 1 and 2 together would be Area(I) + Area(II) which can be written:
$${(0.05)(320-200)\over 2} + (0.05)(200)$$

To add them together you want a common denominator. So multiply the second term by $2\over2$:
$${(0.05)(320-200)\over 2} + {2(0.05)(200)\over2}$$

Then factor out the common factor of $0.05$ from the numerator:

$$(0.05){(320-200)+2(200)\over2}$$

And dropping the brackets gives you:
$$(0.05){320-200+2(200)\over2}$$
$$= (0.05){320+200\over2}$$

Edit: If you want to look at it geometrically rather than algebraically, first note that $(320+200)\over 2$ gives you the midpoint between 320 and 200. If you draw a horizontal line on your graph straight across from this midpoint then you will be cutting region I halfway across the triangle.

Then all you have to notice is that you can take the small piece of the triangle *above* the horizontal line and maneuver it into position so that it fills up the empty space under the horizontal line that is left next to region I.

Once you put that piece of triangle there, you will have a rectangle formed by the horizontal line of height $h = {(320 +200)\over 2}$ and with width $w = 0.05$. Then the area of this rectangle will be given by:

height x width = ${(320+200)\over 2}(0.05)$.